# EWS Exception using Appointment.bind(...)

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

I'm using **com.microsoft.ews-java-api:ews-java-api:2.0** to create and update appointments in a MS Exchange calendar. Both are working fine on my test environment. On the customers environment (different exchange server) creating the appointment works but updating it running the following code leads to an exception.

```java
// Init
ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
WebCredentials webCredentials = new WebCredentials(exchangeUser, exchangePassword);
URI exchangeUri = new URI(exchangeUrl);
exchangeService.setCredentials(webCredentials);
exchangeService.setUrl(exchangeUri);

// Creating an appointment. This works on both environments.
Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox("some@mail.com");
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mailbox);
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(exchangeService);
appointment.save(folderId);
// Keep ID for updating later on ...
model.setAppointmentId(appointment.getId().getUniqueId());

// ...

// Updating an appointment. This only works on my test environment.
ItemId itemId = new ItemId();
itemId.setUniqueId(model.getAppointmentId());
Appointment appointment = Appointment.bind(exchangeService, itemId); // The exception occurs here!
appointment.update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

And this is the exception I get

```java
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.internalThrowIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:278)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.throwIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:267)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:165)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalBindToItems(ExchangeService.java:1343)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.bindToItem(ExchangeService.java:1378)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.bindToItem(ExchangeService.java:1395)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Appointment.bind(Appointment.java:118)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Appointment.bind(Appointment.java:133)
```

`An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.` is not really a helpful exception. Any ideas why this fails? Or how to get more information?

Comment: How are you getting The <id>?

Comment: When I save the appointment `appointment.save(targetFolderId)` with `appointment.getId().getUniqueId()`

Comment: this doesn't make any sense you need to provide your full context code

Comment: if you wanna find the id of a wellknown folder you need to call the FindFolders method of the API the result you will get will have an Id property thats the id you wanna use. have you tried this?